# Application appears in the “share” list ANDROID

Tags: android

How can I do that my application appears in the “share” list of another application? For example, I want to choose a pdf file and send it to my application.

I can’t find the solution, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I mean its a valid question but this has been asked so many times already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788252/best-practice-adding-your-app-to-the-android-share-menu

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424088/make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list?rq=1 and others

Comment: A quick google search will give you instant answers. Please refrain from posting questions that are generic and the solutions to which are already clear. If you have some specific issue, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an intent filter in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

for example for a pdf you can indicate the mimeType `application/pdf`.

`<activity name="package.name.MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Look at the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving